# Is there some way to register custom ttml parser in the CAF framework ChromeCast

Tags: chromecast, shaka

As I know CAF framework uses Shaka player under the hood, is there some way to register custom ttml parser?

https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-plugins.html

`Register with shaka.text.TextEngine.registerParser`